# MVCContrib Grid alternatives for MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, mvccontrib, mvccontrib-grid

I'm working on a greenfield MVC4 project and am in need of a good MVC-grid to support paging and sorting (and i want to handle the paging and sorting myself, not in the grid). I also like the grid to be lightweight (as i want to be in control of html markup and query parameters) and be able to use lambda expressions for columns.

I have previously used MvcContrib Grid in an older MVC2 project and was quite happy with the extensibility. I have experimented a bit with the webhelper grid in this project but it doesn't seem to be nearly as extensible as the MvcContrib Grid. The MvcContrib project however doesn't appear to be as actively maintained anymore. As far as I can see the main version is for MVC2 and I don't really want to have compatibility issued in a brand new greenfield project.

Does anyone know if the MvcContrib project is expected to release a new version for MVC4? Are there any other lightweight and up to date grids for MVC nowadays?

**UPDATE**
I ended up writing my own grid component (and a pager component) with a syntax style loosely based on MvcContrib with the possibility to swap renderers.

Comment: is there no asp gridview for MVC4

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked into jQuery Datatables http://www.datatables.net/

I recently migrated from MVCContrib Grid to jQuery Datatables.  They are pretty awesome.

Here is how we initialize the table.

```
BindTable: function () {
        var that = this;
        this.Table = $('#sorting-advanced');
        var tableStyled = false;

        this.Table.dataTable({
            'aoColumnDefs': [
                { 'aTargets': [1], 'sType': 'num-html' },
                { 'aTargets': [3], 'sType': 'currency' },
                { 'aTargets': [5], 'bSortable': false, }
            ],
            'sPaginationType': 'full_numbers',
            'sDom': '<"dataTables_header"lfr>t<"dataTables_footer"ip>',
            'fnDrawCallback': function (oSettings) {
                // Only run once
                if (!tableStyled) {
                    that.Table.closest('.dataTables_wrapper').find('.dataTables_length select').addClass('select').styleSelect();
                    tableStyled = true;
                }
            }
        });
    },
```

Here is the Razor View

```
  <table class="table responsive-table" id="sorting-advanced">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">Date</th>
                    <th scope="col">Document #</th>
                    <th scope="col">Tenant</th>
                    <th scope="col">Amount</th>
                    <th scope="col" class="align-center">Reconciled</th>
                    <th scope="col" class="align-center">Actions</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var item in Model.Items)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>@item.Date.ToShortDateString()</td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="@Url.Action("Edit", new {id = item.Id})">@item.Number</a>
                        </td>
                        <td>@item.Contact.DisplayName</td>
                        <td>@item.Amount.ToString("C2")</td>
                        <td class="align-center">
                          @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => item.Reconciled, new {id = item.Id})
                        </td>
                        <td class="align-center vertical-center">
                            <span class="button-group compact">

                                <a href="@Url.Action("Edit", new {id = item.Id})" 
                                   class="button icon-pencil with-tooltip"
                                   title="Edit Payment"></a>

                                <a href="#" id="@item.Id" 
                                   class="button icon-trash with-tooltip confirm-delete"
                                   title="Delete Payment"></a>
                            </span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Comment: I saw it mentioned as i was scouting around a bit, but I'm a little bit apposed to the jQuery versions i have seen, party because most of them "class-barfs" a bit, making the markup (at least to my taste) too messy. Also it seems to me that you need a some configuration to map between your view model and your javascript that will not be updated if you do some refactoring (like change property names etc). That's why i prefer to use a strongly typed grid if possible...

Comment: That hasn't been my experience. I can post some sample code from an actual implementation and see what you think.

Comment: I didn't have to map the data to javascript objects.  I just built the table using pretty standard html then initialized the table.  There is a lot more you can do with it but it was pretty straight forward.

Comment: Sure, it would be interesting to see an actual implementation without all the bells and whistles.

Comment: So if understand correctly, you load all the items into the table all at once, and then you let the Datatables framework handle paging and sorting without reloading the page, is that correct?

Comment: Yep. Exactly.  Currently I am just loading all of the items rather than doing server side paging.  But it also supports ajax paging if needed.  It pretty much supports anything you need.

Comment: In our solution it's not feasible to load all items into the list and handle everything from there client side, so we handle paging and sorting server side.

Comment: jQuery dataTables isn't really an "alternative" to Mvccontrib grid - it's more of a complement. Grid helps you encapsulate grid definition in code, dataTables lets you add client-side functions to it, some of which can talk to the server. I use both!